# Groovy - Extract a string between two different strings

Tags: regex, groovy

I have files names in the below format -

```
India_AP_Dev1.txt
USA_GA_QA2.txt
USA_NY_AWSDev1.txt
AUS_AA_BB_QA4.txt
```

I want to extract only the environment part from the file name i.e. `Dev1, QA2, AWSDev1, QA4`etc. How can I go about with this type of file names. I thought about `substring` but the environment length is not constant. Is it possible to do it with `regex`

Appreciate your help. TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is definitely possible using lookarounds:

```
(?<=_)[^._]*(?=\.)
```

- `(?<=_)` match is preceded by `_`
- `[^._]` take all characters except `.` and `_`
- `(?=\.)` match is followed by `.`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/q0ivuq/1)

Comment: `def regexformat = "(?<=_)[^._]*(?=\.)"
      Matcher digitMatcher = Pattern.compile(regexformat).matcher(jsoname);` i am trying out this way but i see the error `unexpected char: '\'`. any suggestions please. `jsoname` will have my file name

Comment: found the issue, one more `\\` is required

Comment: thanks PJ. this worked like a charm!!